# iOS create pdf from UIWebView

Tags: iphone, pdf

I will create the pdf from UIWebView. 
I created the pdf by cropping the UIWebView screen.
Then, I have gotten pdf of only part that is currently displayed on the screen of phone.
I want to get pdf of all webview contents.
Does anyone know to solve this problem?
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You could set scalesPageToFit to YES. Or scroll the webview after rendering each page.